# Why does Excel now require a slash for dates and how do I change it back so it does not?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, format, date

I used to be able to type a date without any separators, ie 062509 and Excel would recognize it and return the date in whichever date format I selected, such as June 25, 2009 or 06/25/2009. Now Excel is interpreting 062509 as just a number and returning 02/20/2071 unless I explicitly type the slashes, 06/25/09.

I'm using Office 365 for Enterprise. Is there any way to change the default behavior back to the way it used to be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What has changed? A new version of Excel? The default Windows date/time formats? International settings?

Comment: What has changed?  Most likely, the VBA (or similar) routine that was interpreting your unseparated date is no longer installed.  I'm pretty certain the behavior you describe was never a part of any version of Windows Excel; and I doubt it was part of non-Windows versions.

Comment: Did you check the Region date formatting in Control Panel?

Answer (score 1):

Ron Rosenfeld is almost dead right about why it no longer works for you. Especially if a Personal workbook contained it and your move to Office 365 Enterprise replaced a purchased, not subscribed to, version.

My memory of 30 years with Excel is that Excel itself never did this.

More importantly, consider this:  to interpret that input as a date, Excel has to realize it is a date, but Excel relies upon Windows, or whatever OS, for what to recognize as a date. Excel does not decide this itself. So if your Windows settings are not set to only regard that exact format of input as a date, then Windows cannot tell Excel it is a date, and Excel will not treat it as a date. For example, even if you opened your default template and set the number format of every cell as "yymmdd" then saved it so that it always gave you new spreadsheets that were foramtted this way from the beginning, it still would not help you because Excel would think "062509" no closer to a date than it would consider "horse" to be. So it would not apply the date format you went to so much trouble to set.

The traditional way has long, long been to write a macro that fires when you move from the cell, or press Enter. That's why a change to (probably) a very different version of Excel, one that REPLACES, not UPGRADES, your program, seems a likely source of the loss. Since you indicate this was available to you in a way that suggests you mean in all your work, not just a particular set of spreadsheets, your Personal workbook in the old version seems a good bet for where the macro was.

If that file might still be on your computer (and bear in mind your Trash directory), you might be able to either use it to replace the new version's Personal workbook completely, or perhaps you could just take the macro from it (assuming this is where it was!) and put it into the new version's Personal workbook. But installation programs usually delete material in a way that does not go through the protection of the Trash concept so...

If you don't try looking, you definitely will not find it available. So, check perhaps...

Or write a new one. It likely wasn't more than 4-5 lines. Just an "On Enter" approach. (If you wanted to convert existing data, things would be more complex, and offer formulaic and formatting approaches too, but you want to take what was entered, the moment you finish the entry, and convert it to a date that can then be displayed however you formatted the cell (for example, you might want to enter it as 062509 but have it displayed as "25, juNE 2009"). That's all the macro need to do:  recognize the moment to act, parse it and make it a date for Excel to act upon, and stop.

I did 20-25 pages of Google hits on various ways of asking, but could not find a country said to use the ISO 8601 format as their national format, hoping to tell you a country setting you could choose in Windows and hope their short formats might offer a selection without dashes or slashes. But as you might guess from all the stuff above existing, I could not find one. And Windows 10 DOES NOT OFFER it in any of the ways website's confidently tell you to set it. But if you really desire it and don't do the macro mentioned, maybe your searches would be more successful.